# Python - proper syntax of .format()

Tags: python, django, formatting

I need to write a .format() like this:

```
"{% display_cookies_accepted {} %}".format(self.client.cookies)
```

{} - need to be replaced by self.client.cookies

{%, %} - is a template tag in django syntax.

How to make it working?

```
"{{% display_cookies_accepted {} %}}".format(self.client.cookies)
```

also fails.

Comment: What is the error and what python are you using?
BTW, your suggestion works for me.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The `'{{% display_cookies_accepted {} %}}'.format(self.client.cookies)` works just fine. What's wrong with it? It doesn't give errors and the output seems correct. You should probably show what are you getting as output and what is your expected output.

Comment: If you're using python 2.6 it will raise `ValueError: zero length field name in format`. You need to do `'{{% display_cookies_accepted {0} %}}'.format(self.client.cookies)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just format the content first, and then add the django tags.

```
"{%" + " display_cookies_accepted {} ".format(self.client.cookies) + "%}"
```

Or put the tags in the format as well.

```
"{} display_cookies_accepted {} {}".format('{%', self.client.cookies, '%}')
```

Comment: I want to use format() to avoid using string concatenation :)